# 128 MB of memory is required to enable direct printing

Tags: java, pdf, lpr

I'm developing a new android application (using java) for remote printing.
The communication with the printer is by LPR standard (RFC 1179).
I wrote the LPR client in Java, and used it to print a PDF document.
It printed very well in the first time.
Then i tried to print again the same document and i received a strange error:

> "PDF status page
>      PDF file not printed. 128 MB of memory is required to enable direct PDF printing."

I searched about this problem, and didn't found very much.
When i'm using the original driver this problem doesn't show up.
Does anyone have any idea how to get over this?

Comment: Provide us some source code of PDF forming algorithm...

Comment: It is possible this message appears if you ever run out of memory, even if you have more than 128 MB. I would look for this message in the code of the library you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and thought I'd provide an answer for my situation.  I migrated to a new server and when trying to print PDF's got the error in the title.  I had forgotten to install the printer driver.

I simply copied my old `ppd` files to `/etc/cups/ppd/`, restarted cups and the error went away.